# Make one user create and edit page and other user approve it. How to do this?

Tags: 2013, workflow, publishing, approval-process, content-approval

I want to achieve this simple functionality using OOB **Approval - SharePoint 2010** and **Publishing** workflows but it is not working.

1. I have two users user1 and user2
2. I want user1 to create and edit pages and user2 to approve those pages to publish
3. I am using **Approval - SharePoint 2010** workflow with option selected *Start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item.*
4. I gave **Contribute** permissions to user1
5. I gave **Approve** permissions to user2
6. When user1 edits a page and checks it back in then nothing happens.
7. When user2 logs in and goes to that page then it shows in yellow bar on top that this page needs to be published. Now here's the problem. Why would user2 publish it which will then start the workflow and then he will approve it?
8. I mean as soon as user1 saved and checked in the page, it should have started workflow and then user2 will be able to approve it and page should be published.

How to achieve this functionality?

**EDIT**

Just to reiterate here is what I want.

1. When user1 edits a page and checks in then workflow should automatically start (which will send email alert to user2 and also add it in his Tasks list as defined in workflow) without him doing anything. If that's not possible then user1 should be able to do it with a single click for e.g. like clicking a button Submit which will then start the workflow.
2. user2 then should be able to approve/reject workflow.

Comment: Sounds like the out of the box Approval workflow bound to a Pages library?

Comment: Yes I managed to make it work but problem is Minor and Major both versions need to be enabled on library to make it work. If I only enable Major versions then the above scenario partially work i.e. although user1 can submit and user2 can approve but workflow doesn't run hence no email is sent nor task is assigned to user.

Comment: I guess minor versions is required in case you get a "No" from the approver, and since you need to have drafts (0.1..) that can be approved (1.0..)

Comment: Oh yes that makes sense. Thanks. But is there a way to shorten the way workflow is started by user1? This is how I am doing currently; edit page, then check in page, then click on Publish tab above and then click on "Start Workflow", then a new window opens which shows my workflow name, click on that name and then finally that workflow window appears where you define to whom it will be sent etc.

Comment: select the "Start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item" check box in workflow settings.

Comment: I have already done that. But workflow doesn't start as soon as user1 checks in. And he has to go through all steps as I mentioned above.

Comment: It should not start until he hits Publish.